# CATCH block does not execute first time but executes second time onwards - Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The catch block does not execute after the first time any edit is made to the script, but works fine from 2nd time onwards.

Below is some script to demonstrate the problem.

```
use master
go

print 'rollback demo'

declare @errordemo bit = 1
select 'Transaction Count Before =', @@TRANCOUNT
begin try
    begin transaction
    if (@errordemo = 0) select 'abc' as column1 into MyTestTable
    insert into MyTestTable values ('xyz')
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
end catch
go

select 'Transaction Count After =', @@TRANCOUNT
go

-- this is only to bring back the system to its previous state
if (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) rollback transaction
go
if exists(select * from sys.tables where name ='MyTestTable') drop table MyTestTable
go
```

Copy the above script in `SQL Server Management Studio` and run it.
You would get the following result with an error.

```
Transaction Count Before =  0
Transaction Count After =   1
```

Press F5 again and again and it will execute successfully with:

```
Transaction Count Before =  0
Transaction Count After =   0
```

which means the catch block executed.

Now comment out the first line `print 'rollback demo'`, or change its text. You will get the error again. Press F5 again any number of times and there is no error. Repeat by uncommenting that line (or making any other change in script) and you can see a predictable/reproducible pattern.

What is going on here?

Below are some screenshots to show what is happening.

When successful:

[image: successful result 1]
[image: successful result 2]

When unsuccessful:

[image: unsuccessful result 1]
[image: unsuccessful result 2]

Comment: You can't catch `Invalid object name` errors.

Comment: @DavidG, why is there no error 2nd time onwards? There is no change in the script except that it is just recompiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your error is **binding error** that cannot be catch in `TRY..CATCH` block.

When you reference a non-existing object, SQL Server does not even try to check its columns, it does not compile this piece of code, it leavs it for the execution time.
This is called `deferred name resolution`.

Only when it comes to the execution of this statement, it checks for table and raises an error.

This is compilation error and cannot be catch within the same scope (only in outer scope).

There is a connect item that you can check:
[Try-catch should capture the parse errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/496758/try-catch-should-capture-the-parse-errors).

So in fact your catch block cannot be reached when this error is raised.

On the next execution, if noone character of your query was changed, the cached plan is used. So it is not compiled on the second execution.

But if you change your query text (try to add -- in any part of it), or if you instruct the server to not to cache the plan(using `recompile` option) like this:

```
declare @errordemo bit = 1
select 'Transaction Count Before =', @@TRANCOUNT
begin try 
    begin transaction
    if (@errordemo = 0) select 'abc' as column1 into dbo.MyTestTable
    print @errordemo 
    insert into dbo.MyTestTable values ('xyz')
    option (recompile) -------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    print 'catch block'
    rollback transaction
end catch
go

select 'Transaction Count After =', @@TRANCOUNT
go

if (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) rollback transaction
```

the plan will not be cached and the query will be compiled every time, and you'll see compilation error every time and your `catch` block will never be reached.

Here is the plan cached:  [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkb8Tl62Z)

And here you can see that there is no real insert plan:

[image]

This is how real Insert plan looks like:
[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried to reproduce the same with `SELECT` query and find any difference in the plan, but I was not able to extract the plan for `SELECT` from plan cache.
The entry for it exists, has the same size as `INSERT` plan, but it's not possible to see this plan, it seems that it's not cached, but the entry does exist...

To reproduce it you can use the following code:

```
/*select query F7CA8D53-E171-4B5F-8CEA-B19461819C0D*/
declare @errordemo bit = 1
select 'Transaction Count Before =', @@TRANCOUNT
begin try 
    begin transaction
    if (@errordemo = 0) select 'abc' as column1 into dbo.MyTestTable
    print @errordemo 
    select * from MyTestTable 
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    print 'catch block'
    rollback transaction
end catch
go

select 'Transaction Count After =', @@TRANCOUNT
go

if (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) rollback transaction;
go
-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
/*insert query C7D24848-E2BB-46E7-8B1B-334406789CF9*/
declare @errordemo bit = 1
select 'Transaction Count Before =', @@TRANCOUNT
begin try 
    begin transaction
    if (@errordemo = 0) select 'abc' as column1 into dbo.MyTestTable
    print @errordemo 
    insert into MyTestTable values(1) 
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    print 'catch block'
    rollback transaction
end catch
go

select 'Transaction Count After =', @@TRANCOUNT
go

if (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) rollback transaction
go
-----------------------
-----------------------
select *
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p
cross APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(p.plan_handle) pl
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (p.plan_handle) t
where (t.text like '%F7CA8D53-E171-4B5F-8CEA-B19461819C0D%' -- select
    or t.text like '%C7D24848-E2BB-46E7-8B1B-334406789CF9%')-- insert
    and t.text not like '%sys.dm_exec_cached_plans%'
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that we can't catch binding or compilation errors. But when there is compilation error, the plan should not be cached, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it chached. It cached without that part for insert as it's deffered. I'll upload the plan and you'll see it

Comment: ++ Nice and helpful answer.

Comment: Any idea why if I replace `insert into MyTestTable values ('xyz')` with `select * from MyTestTable` the error comes every time. So what is with `SELECT` which is not with `INSERT` or vice-versa?

Comment: It's really interesting question. I tried to extract the plan of select batch and...Even the entry exists in plan cache I was not able to extract this plan. I'll update my answer with this and maybe we should ask it at dba.stackexchange?